# Show UIPickerView text field is selected, then hide after selected

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to create a text box that when it is selected a UIPickerView opens up with choices to select from. Once selected, the UIPickerView hides and the selected item is displayed in the text box. I tried different pieces of code I found online but I just can't get it to work. If someone can suggest a complete code for this or tell me what I am doing wrong in my code, that would be super awesome. Thanks so much.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var textfieldBizCat: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pickerBizCat: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()

var bizCat = ["Cat One", "Cat Two", "Cat Three"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var bizCatCount = bizCat.count

    self.textfieldBizCat.inputView = pickerView

}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
    return 1
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return bizCat.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return bizCat[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    textfieldBizCat.text = "\(bizCat[row])"

}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If I understood well your question, you want:

1. Have an `UITextField` which display a text selected
2. Opening a picker when the user click on the `UITextField`
3. Close the picker when an item (in the picker) is selected, and set it in the `UITextField`

This is the complete code to manage it, you just have to link the delegate of your `UITextField`:

```
@IBOutlet var textfieldBizCat: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var pickerBizCat: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()

var bizCat = ["Cat One", "Cat Two", "Cat Three"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pickerBizCat.hidden = true;
    textfieldBizCat.text = bizCat[0]
}

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int{
    return 1
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return bizCat.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return bizCat[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    textfieldBizCat.text = bizCat[row]
    pickerBizCat.hidden = true;
}

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    pickerBizCat.hidden = false
    return false
}
```

What I changed from your code:

- Used `UITextFieldDelegate` to display the picker when the `UITextField` is selected
- Hide the picker once an item is selected, and setup the `UITextField`
- Set the first row of your picker in the `UITextField` when any item is selected

Comment: Thank you for your help Ckouta. It now displays "Cat One" in the text field, but when I click on it, the UIPicker is not appearing.

Comment: Did you set the UITextField delegate from your xib? You can do it also programatically, just add `textfieldBizCat.delegate = self`in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Oh, ok forgot to do that. Also needed to add pickerBizCat.delegate = self to viewDidLoad. Now it works! Thanks so much.

Comment: how would this be modified if you have multiple textfields you want to add a picker to in that view @Ckouta

Comment: That is a another question, I suggest you to ask a new question on stack directly with your actual source code, issue...

Comment: Hi, when I follow your examples I get the error "RegisterViewController does not conform to protocoll UITextDelegate" This error shows when I enter the line with textfieldName.delegate = self. Any help on that?

Comment: @tbaranes can you explain why it's better to use the UITextFieldDelegate textFieldShouldBeginEditing method to display the pickerView vice setting the textfield's inputView = pickerView?  Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495585/swift-hide-pickerview-after-value-selected

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4** version

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.delegate = self

    textField.delegate = self
    textField.inputView = pickerView
}
```

And the extensions

```
// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        pickerView.isHidden = false
        return false
    }
}

// MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myItems.count
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myItems[row].name
    }

    func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        textField.text = myItems[row].name
        pickerView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about in your didSelectRow method you resignFirstResponder?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
textfieldBizCat.text = bizCat[row]
pickerBizCat.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // pressing the button again would hide the uipickerview. when pressed the first time, update the button's label to "done" , "hide" or whatever suits u!
    @IBAction func propertyTypeButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)/* the name of your button's action*/
    {
        count++; //declare it first
        ViewContainigPickerView.hidden = false
        self.view.endEditing(true)

        if (count == 2)
        {
            ViewContainingPickerView.hidden = true /* if you placed your picker on a separate view for simplicity*/
            count = 0;

        }

    }
```