# two uitextfield i want one to be disabled so it cannot be edited - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have two UITextField one is a normal textfield which requires text to be inputted. The other is connected to a UIPickerView. When i click the UITextField which is connected to the pickerView a cursor appears, the textfield is not editable as the keyboard is the pickerView, but text can be copied and pasted into it. Any Help??

I tried to fix it through the UITextFieldDelegate method

```
       func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool { }
```

But it controls both of my textfields and doesn't resolve my issue.

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First, when you implement delegate methods like that, you have to return a different value based on which text field is passed in.  One relatively easy way to do this is to specify a numerical tag for each text field in Interface Builder, and then in your delegate method, compare the passed-in field's tag property to the expected values.

Second, you probably should do this by just setting the enabled property on the text field to NO instead of implementing a delegate method and trying to prevent editing.

Comment: If the textfield is not enabled then when it is clicked on it doesn't show the picker option..

Comment: I tried to separate them with tags and give them there own methods, but the  function requires an return. and after return is implemented any code after isn't taken into affect?

Comment: In your textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate method for the field with a picker view, you also need to explicitly show the picker view.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819423/show-uipickerview-text-field-is-selected-then-hide-after-selected for an example.