# Hide keyboard when a textField is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I want to hide the keyboard every time a user click on the textField named `typeDeProbleme`. So, I did something like below (in the if condition) which in my understanding should've work but unfortunately it's not. Every time I click on the `typeDeProbleme`, the keyboard is stuck and cannot be hidden unless I click on another textField. For your information, `typeDeProbleme` is a textField linked to a PickerView. I also attached a toolbar on top of my keyboard that have a button X to hide the keyboard. Can anyone explain to me where is the problem?

[image]

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.returnKeyType = .next

    if textField == self.typeDeProbleme {
        textField.endEditing(true)// hide keyboard
        textField.resignFirstResponder() //hide keyboard
        self.pbTypePickerV.isHidden = false
    }else{
        keyboardDidShow(vvv: textField)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a textfield to show a picker view?

Comment: You can refer this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819423/show-uipickerview-text-field-is-selected-then-hide-after-selected)

Answer (score 1):

Use this method instead textFieldDidBeginEditing

```
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == typeDeProbleme {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: @zaki you try this line? textField.endEditing(true)

Comment: @zaki you should write self.view.endEditing(true), to call this method from controller, not textField

Comment: I tried your solution but didn't put it in the question

Comment: @zaki are you add delegate to typeDeProbleme? Add a breakpoint

Comment: yes..I did add the delegate for typeDeProbleme...as for the breakpoint I tried to po textField, but what actually I'm looking for?